# How to convert PDF to HTML using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, pdf

I have a PDF file and I want to convert it to HTML using JQuery.

Is it Possible? If Yes the what library should I use or any custom jquery code will be required?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How will your JS code access the PDF file?

Comment: There are so many on line sites which convert pdf file to html, i don't think conversion from pdf to html is possible by jquery

Comment: jQuery can't read and convert PDF files to HTML.

Comment: Upload your file to your server. Render HTML out of it using some library and present it to the browser.

Comment: @AlexR. that is my queystion that how to render HTML out of my pdf file using some library(JQuery library) or Javascript?

Comment: does your pdf contains the html part or ur just want to put it into the body of a predefined html page

Comment: The PDF contains the Text and some images. I want to convert it to html that will use divs.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really possible with jQuery at the time, but there are development being made on things like [pdf.js](http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/) which turns a pdf document into html in the browser, but it does'nt seem to work with all pdf files yet, and there's still some bugs to iron out.

There's also quite a few solutions to this on the serverside, [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) seems to be the one that generates HTML with most likeness to the original document as it uses the webkit rendering engine directly, but it does require some setting up on the server.

[SomePDF](http://www.somepdf.com/some-pdf-to-html-converter.html), [IntraPDF](http://www.intrapdf.com/convert_pdf_to_html.htm), and probably the most widely used [pdftohtml](http://pdftohtml.sourceforge.net/) also all do this on the serverside, and Adobe Acrobat Pro has an option to save pdf files as html.